# Modify the Product page Image with 360 view

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

I am going to modify the Product view page that I want to view the image as a 360-degree view using Alpine Js.
And I want to use this link as a reference:

> https://github.com/moveideas/alpine-product-360

I am using magento 2.4.3 .
Help me out or suggest Steps that I'll follow.
Thanks.

Comment: Using only Alpine Js ?

Comment: yes using alpine, I have setup hyva theme for that.